# Incrementing numbers in Task process

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am struggling to work out how to correctly increment a counter I have in a Task process.

My program creates a bunch of Tasks that manipulate and save images. Part of the process is renaming the files automatically via an incremental counter.

ie: Filename_001.jpg, Filename_002.jpg, Filename 003.jpg

Basic pseudo example below:

```
dim counter as integer = 0
for each file in folder
    tasks.add(task.factory.startnew(sub()
        using imgProcess(image, filename & counter & ".jpg")
        end using
        counter +=1
    end sub))
next
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())
```

I have tried using `Interlocked.Increment` instead of `counter+=1` like below

```
Interlocked.Increment(counter)
```

The process doesn't work correctly as the variable is being accessed by multiple threads and I end up with an incorrect output.

I am sure I am missing something obvious or even committing some massive no-no as am I new to parallelism.. so please go easy on me if so!

I would appreciate any suggestions. I have looked around and can see similar issues relating to threaded "race conditions" but can't seem to make anything work in my particular instance.

Thanks heaps in advance.

Comment: Move the counter outside of the sub. Also use Task.Run and not the factory

Comment: better yet, construct the file name before using it in the delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the counter outside of the Task's Sub. Also use `Task.Run` and not the factory.

Better yet, construct the file name before using it in the delegate.

For example

```
Dim folder() As String = {"file", "file", "file", "file", "file", "file", "file"}
Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()
Dim counter As Integer = 0
For Each filename in folder
    Dim file = filename & "_" & counter & ".jpg"
    Dim task As Task = Task.Run(Sub()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World " & file)
    End Sub)
    tasks.Add(task)
    counter += 1
Next
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())
```

Will safely produce the desired behavior.

Comment: That's very thorough and very informative - and most importantly has solved the problem. Really appreciate that, thanks Nkosi :)